# Cypress E2E fails on basic auth

Tags: javascript, authentication, testing, e2e-testing, cypress

I'm trying to use cypress to cover our dev-server by a set of complete `e2e` tests.

We have a requirement to lock our dev environment under basic http authentication so nobody couldn't access it without proper credentials (both client and api).

When I'm trying to run Cypress tests they fail because of that. Server (nginx) just responds with 401 http-code.

I tried to pass credentials in url like 'user:password@domain.com', and it partially works: cypress is able to reach frontend on domain.com, but it's still unable to send any requests to our backend (api.domain.com) from within the page (using `fetch`) - probably because of different subdomain or something.

I'm looking for a way for forcing it to use those credentials on all requests on a domain or any other workaround that may help me run the tests.

Thanks!

Comment: I was in a similar situation. There is a way to hold `session` data between tests if required. Is that what you would like to achieve. I'll find out what I did for you if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be an auth issue.  `fetch` does not work with cypress.  See https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/687

A workaround for it is to put this into your support/index.js file:

```
Cypress.on("window:before:load", win => {
  win.fetch = null;
});
```

Comment: oh thanks didn't know that. do you know any similar framework that works with fetch?

Comment: No, there really isn't anything similar to Cypress.  Maybe Testcafe, but I'd much rather use Cypress and deal with its current limitations (always more features/fixes coming).  To be clear, you can still test whatever you're trying to test with Cypress, just put that workaround in so it won't use `fetch`.  I bet your current test will work if you put that in.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your code from above is intended to disable fetch, but if my application actually uses it I should make a mock in order to add some request headers, right?

Comment: Or... if I set window.fetch to null, polyfill will actually be used to support it via xhr and cypress would be able to intercept it... wow, it's a tricky solution then :)

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit of a hack, but it works until Cypress supports it properly.  You could probably mock out fetch instead, but this is the quick fix.